# Systemd Required Shared Library Became Blank with File Permission 401

Tags: linux, filesystems, systemd, .so, search-path

I had been using a Linux system with eMMC storage.
The Linux kernel version is 3.10.
I use Systemd to init the system with a custom built file system.

Very occasionally, the system failed to boot. After investigation, the reason happened to be that, some .so required by the Systemd become blank, the file permission was 401. Since the systemd can not get the right dependencies, it just failed to boot.

For the root cause side, I am guessing the power fluctuation might be the one. Can anyone share some experience on this issue?

Edit: add a file permission character example

```
-r-------x 1 root root 0  1月  1  1970 /lib/libasound.so.2
```

Comment: Thanks for your remind. I am moving the topic to Stack Exchange.